# MongoDB Aggregations Java - Efficient distinct count

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

Let's say I have 'events' collection in MongoDB with millions of documents, and each document in that collection looks something like that:

```
{
    id: "fg3df23",
    config_id: "49gjd3s",
    timestamp: 1649158819315,
    .
    .
    .
    status: "active", 
    .
    .
    .
    user_data: {
        ip: "<some IP>",
        country: "US"
        }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the breakdown of the events that in certain config id's list and their timestamp is between a certain range.
The breakdown I need is the status breakdown by country and the country distinct 'user_data.ip' count.
Basically, for each country I'll have the following response:

```
public class CountriesResponse  {
    private int countryTotalDistinctIps;
    private Set<CountryResponse> data;

    public static class CountryResponse {
        private String country;
        private int distinctIPCount;
        private Map<String, Integer> statusBreakdown;
    }
}
```

I'm using Spring data Mongo DB, and for solving the problem I'm using aggregation that looks like that ('configIdsList', 'start', and 'end' are given parameters):

```
        MatchOperation matchOperation = match(Criteria.where("config_id").in(configIdsList)
                .and("timestamp").gte(start).lte(end));
        GroupOperation groupOperation = group("user_data.country", "status")
                .count().as("eventsCount").addToSet("user_data.ip").as("ipsSet");
        ProjectionOperation countriesFields = project("eventsCount", "ipsSet").
        and("user_data.country").previousOperation().andInclude("country").
                and("status").previousOperation().andInclude("status");
```

This returns a list of breakdown objects which looks like that:

```
    private Integer countEvents;
    private String country;
    private HashSet<String> ipsSet;
    private String status;
```

I then go through the breakdown objects lists and create the above response from them.

Note - Existing Indices: 'config_id_1_timestamp_-1', 'config_id_1_status_1_timestamp_-1', 'config_id_1_user_data.country_1_status_1_timestamp_-1', 'config_id_1_user_data.ip_1_timestamp_-1'

The current solution works, but its very slow when there are a lot of events. (takes ~15sec for ~1.3m matching events).

is there more efficient way of doing it?

I have also tried different solution by trying to group by "user_data.country", "user_data.ip", and "status" but this makes out of memory issue in the '$group' stage (there could be millions of distinct IPs) unless I pass through 'allowDiskUsage:true' which makes it a lot slower than the original aggregation query mentioned above.

Comment: "_I have already created the appropriate indices_" - what are they? I believe the best you can do here is a covered query, but we can't say whether or not that's what you've achieved without more info. Ideally in addition to the index definitions themselves you would also be able to provide the `.explain("allPlansExecution")` output for this operation as well

Comment: Hi @user20042973 , thanks for the reply!
I have added the indices to the question, but I can't add the explain since it's to big... is there anything particular there I should add to the question?

Comment: There is no any magic solution. You may try [materialized-views](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/materialized-views/). Store pre-calculated data for a predetermined time period range, eg: ( from 10:00 - 10:30 count:1589, ip:[XXX, YYY, ZZZ]; from 10:30 - 11:00, count:12590, ip:[YY1, YY2, ...]). And then adapt your query to this materialized view.

Comment: You could upload the explain as a gist or to something like pastebin. But regardless none of those indexes look correct to me. If I understand your field names and aggregation correctly, then try an index defined as `{ config_id: 1, timestamp: 1, "user_data.country": 1, status: 1, "user_data.ip": 1 }`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, and sorry for the delay, I was sick. 
@Valijon I thought about this but this will make us store a lot of extra data and won't save much since there isn't a lot of duplications of the IP's (around 1m distinct IP's for 2m events).

user20042973 I have added this index as well and it is now 13sec xD, so it did helped a bit! thanks! any other ideas? 

I'm currently thinking on how we could split this API so we could perform multiple commands in parallel and maybe save time that way. (currently trying to split based on countries)